# Bootstrap Form Not centered while in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper, twitter-bootstrap-form

I'm trying to get my form to be centered while I view it on desktop and most importantly when I view it on a mobile phone, such as Ipad, or even a iPhone.

Here is my Form code

```
     <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <form class="form jumbotron-form">
                            <div class="container">
                                <h3 class="text-center">Find the Business Waiting For You!</h3>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Industry</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">State</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                                        <p><a class="search" href="#">Advanced Search</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    <div class="overlay-detail text-center">
                       <a href="#service"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                     </div>     
                </div>
```

As you can see it is not centerd can someone help me on what im doing wrong. 
here is the link to my site that im working on www.kevineperjesi.com/found6test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reformatting the code that you written to use containers, rows, and columns as they were desired. Every time you want something to be on a new line no matter what, you should put that in a row. If you want 2 items to be able to be inline, they should both be in the same row. Here is an example of how it can be done in a clean way.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="text-center">Find the Business Waiting For You!</h3>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Industry</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">State</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group text-center col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        <p><a class="search" href="#">Advanced Search</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
        <a href="#service"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can greatly utilize the col-xs-* utilities.

If you use a `col-xs-12 col-sm-12` that means that on both the xs and sm screen size, that column will span all 12 columns on the page.

You seemed to want the selects to be 2 across on a medium size and up, so you can put a `col-sm-12 col-md-6` to make it so that sm and smaller, it will span all 12, and md and up it will only span half.

Bootstrap makes columns very very simple. The documents are well done give a lot of useful info for making great websites. Good luck!

http://getbootstrap.com/css/ include the docs for the grid system.

Comment: Thank you! that worked!!! Been trying to fix it for hours!. Anway, I have one other issue, if you go to my site you see I have a background picture of that building.  But when I view it in mobile, I just see the blue background I made but the picture of the building doesn't show up on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Bootstrap CDN files to see where is the actual problem is:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <form class="form jumbotron-form">
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="text-center">Find the Business Waiting For You!</h3>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Industry</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">State</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
              <p><a class="search" href="#">Advanced Search</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="overlay-detail text-center">
    <a href="#service"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, I have all my files correct. That's odd it works for you but not me. Hmmmm

Comment: Try to use the Bootstrap CDN provided by MaxCDN since you are using unedited bootstrap files like you said. It also works for me and it is the latest bootstrap files.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

And if it works, please upvote my answer. It is not bad to use the links as your default bootstrap files. It will just not work if you don't have internet, but you have so nothing to worry about.